# How Ignore the repeat name from sql in php?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Can you help me to display the name one time only,
But other details should be displayed under the same name, "Shanmugam Anbalagan."[image: Dhasboad_pic] [image: SQL_PIC][image: SQL2]

Return Value:-

Shanmugam Anbalagan
Msklb6
Test

Shanmugam Anbalagan
Msklb7
Test

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){

$searchbx = $_POST['search-bx'];


echo "boom";

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Student_Details.Name,Loan_Books.Book_Number,Book_Details.Book_Name FROM Student_Details INNER JOIN Loan_Books ON Loan_Books.MemberID = Student_Details.MemberID INNER JOIN Book_Details ON Loan_Books.Book_Number = Book_Details.Book_Number WHERE Student_Details.MemberID = '$searchbx'"; 

//$sql = "SELECT Loan_Books.Book_Number,Book_Details.Book_Name, FROM Loan_Books INNER JOIN Book_Details ON Loan_Books.Book_Number = Book_Details.Book_Number"; 


$result = $conn->query($sql);

if( (!empty($result->num_rows)) && ($result->num_rows > 0)){





while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){


echo $row['Name']."<br>";
echo $row['Book_Number']."<br>";
echo $row['Book_Name']."<br>";



}
}
```

Comment: Easier to just make 2 separate queries.

Comment: I regret editing this now - I'm not going to squint at a bunch of screen shots to see what is going on. Rather than screen shots, can you just show (in text) the desired result?